# Actionscript 3 Array not displaying list in alphabetical order and total number isn't displaying correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a Shopping List project that will initialize an array with values and then allow the user to add and remove elements. Each time the array changes it will sort the values and display them in the dynamic text box.

I already have a list of text inside the dynamic text box:

- Bread
- Dog Food
- Eggs
- Hamburger
- Milk

**My first issue** is when I type a new item in the input textbox and click the "add item" button the text goes below the last word in the list and is not put alphabetically. For Example, If I type "Apple" the word is suppose to go on top of  "Bread" but instead is placed below "Milk".

**My second issue** is my running total of the number of items in my list. When I make a new list and each time I add a new item my total should display the number of items I applied to the list, but when I test it only displays the number 1 each time.

How can I fix these?

Also how can I remove items from the array/list?
I want to be able to select an item from the list (copy & paste it into the input box) and when I click the remove btn the item will be removed from the list.

Here's my code:

```
addItem_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AddItem);
function AddItem(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var totalItems:int;
    totalItems = int(input_txt.text);
    totalItems += 1;
    totalItems_txt.text = totalItems.toString();

    var newItem:Array = new Array();
    newItem[0] = input_txt.text;
    newItem.sort(Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);
    input_txt.text = "";
    for (var i:int = 0; i<1; i++) {
        output_txt.appendText(newItem[i] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you have some little problems.

The array that you're using to store your items should be a global variable and every time you have just to add the new item to that array, sort it and show its content in a [`List`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/List.html) control, for example, of course for the items number you can use its `length` property, so your code can be like this :

```
var items:Array = [];

addItem_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AddItem);
function AddItem(e:MouseEvent): void 
{
    if(input_txt.text != ''){
        items.push({label: input_txt.text, data: items.length});
        items.sortOn('label', Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);
        list.removeAll();
        list.dataProvider = new DataProvider(items);
    }
    totalItems_txt.text = items.length.toString();
}
```

`list` here can be a `List` control inserted manually to the stage or created via a code like this, after importing the `fl.controls.List` class :

```
var list:List = new List();
addChild(list);
```

For more about how to use arrays, take a look :

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html.
- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html.
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fdc.html.

Hope that can help.